# How to make vertical space around fancyvrb symmetric?

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing, fancyvrb

How can I get rid of the extra space that appears here?

[image]

I want the space above and below the `Verbatim` to be the same, but here it seems that about 4-8pt of extra space is being added only to the bottom.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\fvset{listparameters=\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text. Here is some text,
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
some code
\end{Verbatim}
which continues later.

\end{document}
```

Changing `topsep` does not seem to help

Comment: omit `\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}`?

Comment: `\topsep` is supposed to set the top and bottom margin of lists to the same value. At any rate, if I set `topsep` to `xpt`, I seem to get spacing of `x` and `x+4ish`. The problem persists without it, it's just harder to see.

Comment: Not  great solution, but you could add `\vspace{3.2pt}` immediately before `\begin{Verbatim}`.

Comment: @SandyG: I found that that stretched but the space below does not, meaning the problem reappears in reverse for vertically-stretched pages.

Comment: Is 3.2pt a guess?

Comment: Not a guess. 3.2pt is accurate to within .05pt. You can try `\setlength{\topsep}{-5pt}` and put a capital `H` in the line below to see the gap. But as you observed, it doesn't completely solve the problem.

Comment: The last line has no descenders.  I'm not sure why `fancyvrb` doesn't honor the regular baseline separation, but you could add a `\strut` to the last line (no space separating it from the end of the text) to make sure it happens.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\showoutput`, we can check the detail of latex how to type `Verbatim` env in the log file. The problem seems relate to the frame. When involve the frame, the output before the top rule (left figure) and after the bottom rule (right figure) are shown as follow:

[image]

The extra space after the `Verbatim` env is caused by the `\baselineskip` 5.05556pt. Before the `Verbatim` env there is no this glue value. The reason for this is when start drawing the the frame rule, `\baselineskip\z@` was set. See the related frame code in `fancyvrb.sty` file (line: 812 to 830):

```
\def\FV@BeginListFrame@Single{%
  \lineskip\z@
  \baselineskip\z@  
  \ifx\FancyVerbFillColor\relax
    \let\FV@FrameFillLine\relax
  \else
    \@tempdima\FV@FrameRule\relax
    \multiply\@tempdima-\tw@
    \edef\FV@FrameFillLine{%
      {\noexpand\FancyVerbFillColor{\vrule\@width\number\@tempdima sp}%
      \kern-\number\@tempdima sp}}%
  \fi
%% DG/SR modification begin - May. 19, 1998
%%  \FV@SingleFrameLine
  \FV@SingleFrameLine{\z@}%
%% DG/SR modification end
  \penalty\@M
  \FV@SingleFrameSep
  \penalty\@M}
```

So if we add a `\vspace{5.05556pt}` before the `Verbatim` env, it should give almost same vertical space (There are still some rubber length during the type out, they are not in exact value I think) between above and below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{listparameters=\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

Here is some text.
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
some code
\end{Verbatim}
which continues later.

Here is some text.
\vspace{5.05556pt}\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single]
some code
\end{Verbatim}
which continues later.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way for me to remove the space below instead, possibly via `xpatchcmd`?

Comment: I already tried `\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\vspace{4pt}}` which seems equivalent to what you suggest, but this resulted in the top space being stretched undesirably on some underfull pages. Perhaps something else is going wrong

Comment: Is there any reason, you must use the frame from ‘verbatim?’ I suggest use other frame package such ‘tcolorbox’

Comment: The un-XY is that I'm using fancyverb via `minted` with `frame=single`

Comment: @Eric `tcolorbox` also have minted supported. you can take a look.